# Update procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a procedure in SQL server:

I'm new on SQL server & I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Course_Name"

My procedure is:

```
USE [Hyaline management System]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUpdateCourseID] 
@CourseID int
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Update Course SET
    Course_Name = @Course_Name,
    Course_Duration = @Course_Duration
where CourseID = @CourseID;

END
```

Can someone please point me where I'm going wrong? and the solution?

Answer (score 3):

It appears, you are missing a few parameters.  Since you are doing an `UPDATE` of the `Course_Name` and `Course_Duration`, you might need to pass them into the stored procedure:

```
USE [Hyaline management System]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUpdateCourseID] 
    @CourseID int,
    @Course_Name varchar(50),      -- change to the proper datatype
    @Course_Duration varchar(100)  -- change to the proper datatype
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Course 
    SET Course_Name = @Course_Name,
        Course_Duration = @Course_Duration
    WHERE CourseID = @CourseID;

END
```

Comment: @user1783853 happy to help, if an answer helped then be sure to accept it via the checkmark on the left.  It will help future visitors and you will get reputation from accepting. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUpdateCourseID] 
    @CourseID int,
    @Course_Name varchar(max),
    @Course_Duration int -- just a guess, minutes as an int?
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Update Course
   SET Course_Name = @Course_Name,
       Course_Duration = @Course_Duration
 WHERE CourseID = @CourseID;
GO
```

It says

> Must declare the scaler variable "@Course_Name"

Because you haven't declared it.  It looks like you want that variable as an input to the SP, so you need to add it in the parameters section before the `"AS"` lead into the body section.

*p/s - Please cut and paste error messages.  This error is understandable, but some others are easier to search on Google if you provided it correctly.  This one should have stated **scalar** (a) not **scaler**.*